# What precautions must I take when using custom index commands with memoir?

Tags: memoir, indexing

I'm trying to write my own indexing front-end commands to do things such as highlighting the primary reference, but something seems to be wrong with the sorting. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\colorlet{indexmain}{Red3}
\newcommand{\ixxmain}[1]{{\bfseries\color{indexmain}#1}}
\newcommand{\ixmain}[1]{\index{#1|ixxmain}}
\newcommand{\id}{\textsc{id}}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Hallo! I need this to get some output on pass 1.
\ixmain{session id@session \id{}}
\index{session id@session \id{}!structure}
\ixmain{session id@session \id{}!uniqueness}
\backmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image: screencap of output pdf]

and on inspecting the `.idx` file the thot plickens:

```
\indexentry{session id@session \textsc  {id}{}|ixxmain}{1}
\indexentry{session id@session \id{}!structure}{1}
\indexentry{session id@session \textsc  {id}{}!uniqueness|ixxmain}{1}
```

My questions are:

1. How do I stop `\id{}` from being expanded here?
2. Given that, in any case, the first-level *keys* are the same (I think), what is `makeindex` doing (the `.ind` file reflects the output, of course)?

Clarification: I've tried running `makeindex` both with and without the `-c` parameter.

Comment: You may find `\string` helpful here. I don't have time to test, but it will help with how the index commands add 'space' between font commands/declarations and their argument.  Try using it before the `\id` in the `\ixmain` commands ... and *not* in the `\id` command as I previously (stupidly) suggested.

Comment: @jon: Thanks, but that seems to interfere with plain `\index` entries

Comment: @jon: Followed your new suggestion, but it still appears to be getting expanded early

Comment: I should also mention: the spacing alone in the `.idx` will cause different entries: `session \textsc{id}` will be indexed separately from `session \textsc {id}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\index` reads its argument semi-verbatim, which is why the basic `\index` prevents `\id` expanding, but within a macro the catcode changes have no effect.

These days you can simplify the expansion control using `\detokenize` something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\colorlet{indexmain}{Red3}
\newcommand{\ixxmain}[1]{{\bfseries\color{indexmain}#1}}
\newcommand{\ixmain}[1]{\index{#1|ixxmain}}
\newcommand{\id}{\textsc{id}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\oldindex\index
\def\index#1{\oldindex{\detokenize{#1}}}%
}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
Hallo! I need this to get some output on pass 1.
\ixmain{session id@session \id{}}
\index{session id@session \id{}!structure}
\ixmain{session id@session \id{}!uniqueness}
\backmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Well that is a much more global solution.  Is there anything that `\detokenize` might cause `makeindex` to choke on or screw up?

Comment: It's probably OK, \index uses a "classic tex" verbatim mechanism so basically doesn't work if the argument contains macros and is used within the argument of another command, the e-tex detokenize is designed to make things safe without the restrictions in catcode changes. Of course someone somewhere wil have a document that _relies_ on \index not working as designed, and having macros expand, but in general \detokenize is I think closer to the original intent.

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks.  This will certainly simplify the construction of my indices, which tend to have a lot of italic entries and so forth (which makes indexing even more annoying to do than it already is).

Comment: Thanks a lot, David, that works beautifully (though I would hardly have expected less :)). One supplementary question: why does one need the `\AtBeginDocument`, rather than putting it in-line? Is that just in case it turns into a package, or is there some deeper TeXZeN involved?

Comment: it didn't work inline (visibly \index definition hadn't changed) so I just guessed memoir or something else loaded was delaying the definition so I delayed the redefinition:-)

Answer (score 2):

(This was too long for a comment.)

If I write the your index commands in the following way:

```
\ixmain{session id@session \string\id{}}
\index{session id@session \id{}!structure} 
\ixmain{session id@session \string\id{}!uniquenes}
```

then the `.idx` file looks like this:

```
\indexentry{session id@session \id{}|ixxmain}{1}
\indexentry{session id@session \id{}!structure}{1}  
\indexentry{session id@session \id{}!uniqueness|ixxmain}{1}
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're hoping for, however.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}  
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} 
\colorlet{indexmain{Red3}  
\newcommand{\ixxmain}[1]{{\bfseries\color{indexmain}#1}} 
\newcommand{\ixmain}[1]{\index{#1|ixxmain}}
\newcommand{\id}{\textsc{id}}     
\newcommand{\sessionid}[1][]{session \id\ixmain{session id@session \string\id{}#1}}% 

%% to compare the difference between using \string or not
%% independent of \ixxmain's fontifying effects:
\newcommand{\sessionidd}[1][]{session \id\index{session id@session \string\id{}#1}}%
%% uncomment this one to see the difference:
% \renewcommand{\sessionidd}[1][]{session \id\index{session id@session \id{}#1}}%
\makeindex
\begin{document}      
Hallo! I need this to get some output on pass1.  
What about the \sessionid[!not unique]  
More about the \sessionid?!    
\newpage
\ixmain{session id@session \string\id{}}        
\index{session id@session \id{}!structure} 
\ixmain{session id@session \string\id{}!uniqueness}  
\backmatter 
\printindex   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, not quite what I was looking for - writing `\string` is about the same amount of work as writing `|ixxmain` (and the latter can be shortened. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No, the index is much more diversified than that - those are all the "session ID" entries; I stripped out a zillion others to make the MWE.

Comment: Yes. Many thanks for your effort and thoughts.

Comment: No, if I use `\index{...|ixxmain}`, everything's fine, and the `.idx` file is unexpanded.

Comment: OK, when you mean in q. 1 (stop being expanded here), you mean in `\ixmain`?  That is only stopped by `\string`; and therefore the best solution is to wrap `\ixmain` into yet another indexing command (which is hard here without seeing how you're using `\ixmain` in relation to the words of the document body).  There is nothing as far as I know that you can do to `\ixxmain` that will help.

Comment: ... and by 'only' I meant 'the only way I knew about', which usually means that there are about five other ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

[David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66004/344) works nicely, until I add `hyperref` back in. (I took this out for the MWE.) With hyperref in place, the solution generates malformed `.idx` entries:

```
-->                                  ?       ?
\indexentry{session id@session \id {}|ixxmain|hyperpage}{8}
```

So, with hyperref, the solution I'm using is to replace my `\index` items with my own `ixnorm`, which operates in a similar manner to `ixmain` and effectively does the same as David's `\detokenize`:

```
\newcommand*{\ixxnorm}[1]{{\hyperpage{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ixnorm}[1]{\index{#1|ixxnorm}}
```

This appears to be an effective solution, though if I need additional function (such as see also) it may shoot me in the foot later.